Android Studio - Error: Unresolved Reference: onEvent, not being called
I'm trying to work on a project, but I seem to have come across an error that has stumped me. I made this event called onEvent in a Kotlin Class called UserInputViewModel:
class UserInputViewModel : ViewModel()
{
    var uiState = mutableStateOf(UserInputScreenState())

    fun onEvent(event: UserDataUiEvents) {
        when (event) {
            is UserDataUiEvents.UserNameEntered -> {
                uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(
                    nameEntered = event.name
                )
            }

            is UserDataUiEvents.AnimalSelected -> {
                uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(
                    animalSelected = event.animalValue
                )
            }
        }

And I'm trying to get this other Kotlin file called UserInputScreen to call the onEvent function from the UserInputViewModel Class using this code:
TextFieldComponent(onTextChanged = {
                UserInputViewModel.onEvent(
                    UserDataUiEvents.UserNameEntered(it)
                )
            })

Unfortunately, I get an error when I try typing in OnEvent called Unresolved Reference: onEvent, even though I clearly set up the OnEvent function in another class, but the app is acting like onEvent was never established. How do I fix this issue? Am I missing a certain line of import or package code to enable event handling? Let me know if you have an answer.

onEvent is a function on an object of type UserInputViewModel. What you try to access is a function of the class UserInputViewModel (respectively its companion object). That doesn't exist, hence the error. You need to get an instance of the view model class first, then you can access the function.

Thank you! Can you please share with me the code on how to create an instance for UserInputViewModel? That would really help!

Take a look at the documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Please understand, I am rather new at Kotlin programming, so this documentation is a little confusing to me, so can you please explain to me in simpler detail how to create the instance for the UserInputViewModel class containing the onEvent function?

One way is to retrieve the view model in the activity: private val viewModel: UserInputViewModel by viewModels()
